# How do I build without re-configuring with cmake tools in vs code?

Tags: c++, cmake, cmake-presets

#### Question

Question in the title.

#### Context:

My project has recently moved to linux and VS Code as apposed to Windows and Visual Studio.

I have successfully set up my cmake tools plugin and am able to configure, build and run the debugger. However, I have encountered one small nuisance. When I press the build button, it will re-configure before building even if I have made no changes to my CMakeLists.txt.

We have an in house tool which does our configuration for us. I have no idea how it works, except that it is a wrapper around cmake. Usually, the configuration results from using the wrapper vs using cmake directly are compatible, but not always. So I'd like to configure with our tool, but build with the cmake tools plugin. Also, it saves time not to configure twice...

#### My Efforts:

I've been presented with this tool bar:

[image]

From pouring over the CMake docs, I've determined that there is a *CMakePresets.json* which contains this `p_debug` build preset which is associated with the `make-Debug` configure preset. This makes sense to me from a high level... but I see no option to specify that I don't need to re-configure every time I press the `build` button.

Further, I have no idea what  `[[Targets In Preset]]` means... I've looked at the `p_debug` preset in the *CMakePresets.json* file. Ther are no "targets" listed... so I don't know if there is something there that I'm missing? This is the entirety of what is contained in the build preset:

```
"buildPresets": [
        {
            "name": "p_debug",
            "configurePreset": "make-Debug",
            "jobs": 40
        },
]
```

Anyway, I'm definitely a little lost and in the weeds trying to figure out how to accomplish this seemingly basic task. Help is appreciated.

Comment: "When I press the build button, it will re-configure before building even if I have made no changes to my CMakeLists.txt" - It is possible that the project itself is responsible for such reconfiguration. Is the issue reproduced with the simple CMake project (for which you could provide the code)?

Comment: If you run `cmake --build` from the commandline, does that _also_ trigger a reconfigure? If so the culprit is your "in house tool".

Comment: @Botjie I tested `cmake --build` and it does not kick off configuration. It goes straight to building.